# Collecting Api Returns In An Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am making a call to a 3rd party api and I am having problems collecting all the returns and returning them as 1 array In my API. I can see that I am successfully making the calls and they are returning. Due to asynch the final array is returning before it is populated. Is there an elegant solution to handling this?

```
var itemIds = ['1','2','3','4','5','6']

exports.getItemData = function getItemData(req, res) {
    var items = [];
    var errors = [];

    for(var itemId in itemIds) {
        var options = {
            uri: itemEndpoint + itemIds[itemId] +'/',
           json: true
        };

        RequestPromise(options).then(function (item){
            console.log(item);
            items.push(item);

        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log(err)
            errors.push(err);

        });
    };
    res.type('application/json');
    res.json(items);
};
```

Comment: [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Felix is right. You need to create an array of `RequestPromise(options)` Promises and then use the `Promise.all([array-of-promises]).then(function (<array-of-result-arrays>){})`.

So your refactored code will look like this:

```
var allPromises = [];
for(var itemId in itemIds) {
        var options = {
            uri: itemEndpoint + itemIds[itemId] +'/',
           json: true
        };
        allPromises .push(RequestPromise(options));
}
//so now you have an array of promises in allPromises. Now when they all resolve:
Promise.all(allPromises).then(function (allResults){
       console.log(allResults);
       //do whatever with the results...
   }).catch(function(err){
       console.log(err)
       errors.push(err);
   });
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I am glad this helped. If you have not done so already, please vote the answer. Happy coding.